# Align elements in a row xml

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, layout

I'm not good with some details of the xml, and I can't found a solution for the next problem.

I have a ListView. One row is defined like next xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/date"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#ff888888"
            android:textSize="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:text="02 OCT"
            android:textStyle="bold"
         />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:textColor="#ff000000"
            android:textSize="14dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:text="GIRLFRIEND COFFE AT STARBUCKS COFFE"
            android:maxWidth="250dip"
         />
         <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:background="@drawable/icon_clip"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/img_posted_check"
        />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/relleno"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="#ff000000"
            android:textSize="14dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:text=""
         />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/amount"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#ff000000"
            android:textSize="14dp"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:text="$13.34"
         />
</LinearLayout>
```

If the text is short, I can see ok:
[image]

But if the text description is so long, it takes all space until the limit of the window and is cropped with "..." ejecting the price and the clip marker:
[image]

I can do this, only if I don't use the clip adding the weight attribute to the text view with title id (@+id/title) and without the layout with the id 'relleno'.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish exactly? Your `TextView` is set to `android:singleLine="true"`, if you remove this line then your text will wrap to the next line.

Comment: I want the next elements: date, description, clip image (optional), and price (aligned to right). All in only one line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is what you want

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/date"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:text="02 OCT"
    android:textColor="#ff888888"
    android:textSize="10dp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/img_posted_check"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/date"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:maxWidth="250dip"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="GIRLFRIEND COFFE AT STARBUCKS COFFE"
    android:textColor="#ff000000"
    android:textSize="14dp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img_posted_check"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/relleno"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/relleno"
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/amount"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text=""
    android:textColor="#ff000000"
    android:textSize="14dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/amount"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:text="$13.34"
    android:textColor="#ff000000"
    android:textSize="14dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Not exactly. The icon must be with the description text.

Answer (score 0):

Then you can replace imageview with textview..,use this

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/img_posted_check"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_launcher" 
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"

        android:text="hiiii" />
```